# How to create the function below?

Tags: python

This is the function I was given: a function that receives the number of students as an argument, and creates a list of random integers of that size. The complete list is returned to the calling statement. The function called def grade_list is the one I came up for the function I needed however it doesn't print anything.

My code so far:

```
def user_num():
    return int(input("How many students are in this imaginary class? "))

def grade_list(user_num):
    gradeList = []
    gradeList.append(randint(1, 99))
    return gradeList

numValue = user_num()
gradeValue = grade_list(user_num)
```

Comment: What is the point of the user_num variable in grade list? If I enter in 50 as an input, are you trying to get a list of 50 random numbers from 1-99?

Comment: Well its supposed to take the user_num as an argument.

Comment: First off, where in `grade_list()` do you print the list, if anywhere? Second, how many elements are going to be in `gradeList[]` when you return it?

Comment: There is no `print()` statement.

Comment: @DemarcusThompson What is the value of `user_num` as defined globally, and is it the value you meant to pass? Note that a function reference is a valid value. Did you mean to pass `numValue` instead?

Comment: Oh crap can't believe I forgot that, Its suppose to make a list of how many you put in with the user_num function

Comment: In the function, it did say that the number of students needs to be taken as an argument and in order to get the number of students I made the function called user_num

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must add iteration with input number and then make loop for add random value to list and finally call print for see the result

```
import random


def user_num():
return int(input("How many students are in this imaginary class? "))

def grade_list(user_num):
    numValue = user_num()
    gradeList = []
    i=0
    while i<numValue:
        gradeList.append(random.randint(1, 99))
        i=i+1
    return gradeList


gradeValue = grade_list(user_num)
print(gradeValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
import random
def user_num():
    return int(input("How many students are in this imaginary class? "))

def grade_list(user_num):
    gradeList = [random.randint(1, 99) for i in range(int(user_num))]
    return gradeList

numValue = user_num()
gradeValue = grade_list(numValue)

print(gradeValue)
```

As others have said, you want to pass numValue, not the function. Note that you have named your function user_num, while the number that you want is stored in the numValue variable.

Output:

```
How many students are in this imaginary class? 50
[24, 89, 78, 86, 27, 43, 87, 84, 35, 21, 7, 70, 97, 48, 8, 41, 11, 83, 6, 19, 58, 94, 62, 67, 5, 46, 19, 30, 75, 37, 64, 37, 35, 30, 43, 19, 26, 23, 43, 60, 56, 4, 38, 95, 29, 69, 35, 49, 83, 66]
```

Comment: So why is that numValue is passed?

Comment: @DemarcusThompson numValue is the variable that holds the value of what is returned by your user_num function (i.e. what you input into the keyboard). If you pass user_num you are passing a function rather than an integer as an argument into grade_list.